# How to construct the pipeline for ner & archive better results using spacy?

Tags: nlp, model, pipeline, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm currently trying to do named entity recognition for tweets using spacy. For that purpose i created with Gensim word vectors which I'm using to train a new blank ner model. At the moment I am a bit confused how the set up the pipeline for my purpose. Regarding this, I have the following question:

- The pipeline which I'm currently using consists only of one ner component. Have someone recommendations for construction the pipeline (e.g. using tok2vec before ner)?

I also wonder if my approach of training a new model with previously created word vectors is the right one and how i could further improve my prediction accuracy.

Comment: Have you seen the spaCy course? It specifically covers creating an NER pipeline, and explains the role of word vectors a bit. https://course.spacy.io/en/

Comment: Thank you for the response. I already have done that course. I'm currently looking for best practices to train an ner model for my domain specific case.